# NUXT 3.5.1 using generic type in setup script tag raises an error " Unresolvable type reference or unsupported built-in utility type""

Tags: html, typescript, vue.js, web, nuxt3

I made an application using NUXT 3.5.1 but when I am trying to use the Vuejs 3.3 new feature generic in the setup script it raises an error :

```
<script lang="ts" setup generic="T">
const p = defineProps<T>();//=ts error:Cannot find name 'T'.ts(2304)
...
</script>
error:
  ERROR  Internal server error: [@vue/compiler-sfc] Unresolvable type reference or 
unsupported built-in utility type

F:/Vue-Projects/Syncfusion-App/components/ProductCard.vue
22 |  import { IProduct } from './types';
23 |  
24 |  const p = defineProps<T>();
   |                        ^
25 |  const count = defineModel<number>('count', { default: 0 });
26 |  const emit = defineEmits(['clicked'])
```

[image]

Comment: Try switching to Volar pre-release version. That will fix the `Cannot find name 'T'.ts(2304)` error.